# how to immediately login through ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh

Here is my problem. I need to run a command
./deploy.sh -u 1540

This will fetch version 1540 of deploy.sh on SVN

When I do, the script access SVN and ask for a password. I'm using ssh. It will first ask me a password since it guesses my SVN login is the same as my login in bash. It's not. So I have to press enter once to skip it. Then I have to enter my username, and then password to login.

**Summary**
My ssh command do bash. Here is what I tried so far

1-) `bash -c '\''timeout 3d ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.157.60 "./deploy.sh -u 1540 && $2 && $3 && $4`

2-) $2 would need to be "press enter" : as of now I tried `echo ""`

3-) $3 would need to be enter login : as of now : `echo "myLogin"`

4-) $4 would need to be enter password : as of now : `echo "mypass"`

**Note :**
Even if I make it work that way, would I need sleep between in case of delays?

Comment: It's not guessing your login name; you're saying you want to log in as `root` with `root@192.168.157.60`.

Comment: The echo idea might work if you pipe those values to the standard input of the bash/ssh/svn process (instead of running them as independent commands). That being said you could also use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to script this interaction. As to getting `svn` to use the right user in the first place you need to configure svn for that or pass it the information on the command line.

Comment: @chepner The problem is svn "guessing" not ssh being told what to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH logins can be passwordless with the use of key authentication.

Arch has a great documentation page on how to set it up, with steps that should work on most ditributions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys

It boils down to these basic steps (details in linked document):

1. Generate keypair
2. Copy public key to authorized keys on target host

---

SVN can be configured for public read access (hence no login credentials will be needed).
Otherwise username and password can be passed as command line arguments, like:

```
svn export --username $USER --password $PASS -r $REV $URL
```

These arguments work with commands other than `export` too. More information with `svn <command> --help`.